# Program quits without taking user input in argparse example

Tags: python

I am new to python. I tried to run below python code in pycharm but without taking user input it exits. Any help?

```
import math
import argparse

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='calculate the area of a cylinder')
parse.add_argument('radius', type=int, help='Radius of the Cylinder')
parse.add_argument('height', type=int, help='Height of the Cylinder')
args = parse.parse_args()


def cylinder_volume(radius, height):
    vol = math.pi * (radius ** 2) * (height)
    return vol


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(cylinder_volume(args.radius, args.height))
age = input("take input")
print("The input is",age)

#C:\Users\manoj\venv\argparse_demo\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/manoj/PycharmProjects/argparse_demo/new.py
#usage: new.py [-h] radius height
#new.py: error: the following arguments are required: radius, height

#Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: how did you run the program? `python new.py 10 20` should work

Comment: the age and second print statements need to be indented to be carried out

Comment: That's weird because the argparse documentation says that the `required` parameter should default to False (since the user expects *options* to be *optional*). What happens if you add `required=False` to the two add-argument statements?

Comment: arg parser takes command line arguments, so when you invoke your module, you need to pass values in order
    python new.py *radius int* *height int*

Comment: you should be able to add line arguments by editing the run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite a redundat use of both command line argument and `input()`. I think doing examples with `input()` take syou on a wrong path in python programming, they also make bad question of StackOverflow with undetermined/unreplicable results. I was trying to make this point [here earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369005/should-user-input-questions-be-sorted-out-or-treated-differently?noredirect=1#comment597185_369005), but with very limited support from community.

In this particular case the line swith input seem very redundant. You just seem to learn passing the arguments through command line and then you want to play with `input()` - which seems a step back.

Answer (score 0):

argparse takes only sys.argv arguments. To use argparse, you need to specify your arguments through command line, like: python new.py argument1 argument2
If you want to use input() for interactive purposes, pass the return value of input() to your function and don't use argparse.